# JQ Tree not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, jqtree

I have a JQ tree in which I am trying to load areapaths in a tree structure.

I have `LoadTree()` method called from `document.ready` and this method makes an ajax call which gets a list of objects (with properties like `DisplayName`).

By looping the result data I am creating the data string which I want to bind. However, when I bind the data, the data does not render properly they all get rendered one character per line.

Refer to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoghM.jpg):

[image]

```
function LoadTree() {
    var jsonData = '[';
    //var finalData = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@this.FullyQualified("/Metrics/LoadAreaPaths")",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resultData) {

            for (var i = 0; i < resultData.TreeViewModels.length; i++) {
                jsonData += '{ label:' + "'" + 
                    resultData.TreeViewModels[i].DisplayName + "'" + ',';
                //children
                jsonData += 'children: [{ label: ' + "'" + 'child3' +"'"+ '}]'
                //last bracket
                jsonData += '},'
            }
            jsonData += '];';
            //finalData = jQuery.parseJSON(resultData);
        }
        //debugger;

    });

    $('#tree1').tree({
        data: jsonData
    });

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the tree inside the callback function. You should also present a javascript object instead of a string:

```
function LoadTree() {
    var jsonData = '[';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@this.FullyQualified("/Metrics/LoadAreaPaths")",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resultData) {

            for (var i = 0; i < resultData.TreeViewModels.length; i++) {
                jsonData += '{ label:' + "'" + 
                    resultData.TreeViewModels[i].DisplayName + "'" + ',';
                //children
                jsonData += 'children: [{ label: ' + "'" + 'child3' +"'"+ '}]'
                //last bracket
                jsonData += '},'
            }
            jsonData += '];';

            var finalData = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);

            $('#tree1').tree({
                data: finalData 
            });
        }


    });
}
```

Comment: How does it make difference?

Answer (score 0):

The data you are constructing is wrong. Use below instead of the code written inside success callback. You are constructing a array without starting `[`.So it is trying to iterate through string as array, so it will consider each character as an array item, because of this you are getting new line for each character. And that is not a good solution to construct array.

```
 var jsonData = [], src = resultData.TreeViewModels;
 for (var i = 0, l = src.length; i < l; i += 1) {
     jsonData.push({
       label: resultData.TreeViewModels[i].DisplayName,
       children: [{
          label: "child3"
       }]
      });
  }
  $('#tree1').tree({
      data: jsonData 
  });
```